# Animating nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery

On one of my pages I use `Isotope` plugin. I hadn't known this before but `Chrome` flattens the `z-order` when using `css3 transforms`. So initially my nested menu was looking quite better with opacity changes and proper z-index. Problem is that nested `ul` goes under the content div.

Then I thought that it would be cool to apply resizing (by the nested `ul`) and change parent `ul` background on hover. So finally I've got this:

http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/xARgS/101/

- How do I improve scripting here? Is it possible to optimize it?
- Looking it in `IE8` is like a natural disaster! Why?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for your fiddle very help full for the drop down menu

Comment: I really glad it can be helpful for somebody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hover event for changing the css class to change the backgroundcolor is a bit clumsy: just use css :hover

You could also improve it by adding animation: http://jsfiddle.net/xARgS/102/

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem might be that every time that you hover over a nav item you have to visually resize the main navigation bar. Try removing the visual styling from that bar and adding a wrapper div with relative or absolute positioning and use its z-index to place it behind the navigation elements.

Comment: Microsoft's SQL Server 2012 page has a good example of what I think you're trying to do here for navigation. You may want to use it as a guide and try to mimic its styling (link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/default.aspx)